# "Unchecked runtime.lastError: At least one data type doesn't support filtering by origin." error while attempting to run extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome extension to clear browsing data based on origin. Documentation in https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData#type-RemovalOptions says it will be available in Chrome 74. I updated to Chrome Version 74.0.3729.108 (Official Build) (64-bit) today but I encountered the error when running the code. Ultimately, it completes successfully and shows the popup.html with the correct data but the error concerns me since I cannot afford to have all user's browsing data wiped clean.

I tried adding originTypes but not sure how to test if it works. Completed successfully with errors
I commented out the origins and clicked the extension and it completed with no errors.

> manifest.json

```
{
  // Required
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "PCI History eraser",
  "version": "2019.04.11.1438",

  // Recommended
  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "Clears PCI history when clicked",
  "icons": {
    "128": "128.png"
    },

  // Pick one (or none)
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "128.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  //permissions to clear browsing data - cache and hosted app data
  "permissions": [
          "browsingData"
        ]
}
```

> popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3 id="popup"></h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

> popup.js

```
var callback = function(){
    document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML = "PCI history cleared. Restart browser";
}

chrome.browsingData.remove({
        "originTypes": {
          "protectedWeb": true
        },
        "origins": [
            "http://xyzserver:5884",
            "http://abcserver:5884"]
      }, {
        "appcache": true,
        "cache": false,
        "cacheStorage": true,
        "cookies": true,
        "downloads": true,
        "fileSystems": true,
        "formData": false,
        "history": true,
        "indexedDB": true,
        "localStorage": true,
        "pluginData": true,
        "passwords": false,
        "serviceWorkers": true,
        "webSQL": true
      }, callback);
```

Comment: See the documentation - it explicitly says "Only supported for cookies, storage and cache".

Comment: Ah, I see. So in the list of DataTypeSet, it would apply only to the following:
appcache, cache, cacheStorage, cookies, and localStorage?